# Algebra of invariants is finitely generated

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A$ be a finitely generated $k$-algebra for a field $k$, and $G$ a finite group which acts on $A$ by ring automorphisms. There is a widely known theorem which states that the algebra $A^G=\{a\in A| \forall g\in G, ga=a\}$ is finitely also generated. (Note that in general subalgebras of finitely generated algebras are not necessarily finitely generated!) Could you give me a link to a proof or give a hint to prove it?

Comment: You have to assume that $A$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra for a field $k$.

Comment: Of course, I meant it but forgot to note it

Answer (score 4):

The original reference is:

> Emmy Noether, *Der Endlichkeitssatz der Invarianten endlicher Gruppen*, Mathematische Annalen, vol. 77, p. 89-92, 1915, [link](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01456821)

A more modern reference is Theorem 13.17 in

> David Eisenbud, *Commutative Algebra: with a view toward algebraic geometry*. Vol. 150. Springer, 1995.

For more details, see chapter 7 of

> David Cox, John Little and Donal O’Shea, *Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms: an introduction to computational algebraic geometry and commutative algebra*, Undergraduate Texts in Mathematics, Springer, 1992

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I did not downvote:)

Answer (score 0):

Hermann Weyl, The Classical Groups: Their Invariants and Representations.

Jean Dieudonne, J.B. Carrell, Invariant Theory Old and New.

There are Russian translations of these books.